# combining array objects into single object

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

Using Rxjs 5.0, I have an object like this

```
var data = [
    {name: 'abc', title: 'zzz', data: '', id: ''},
    {name: 'abc1', title: 'zzz1', data: '', id: ''},
    {name: 'abc2', title: 'zzz2', data: '', id: ''},
    {name: 'abc3', title: 'zzz3', data: '', id: ''}
]
```

I want to simple map it, to retain just name and tile. So did something like this

```
Rx.Observable.from(data)
    .map(item => return {name: item.name, title: item.title};)
    .subscribe(items => console.log('Final OBJ:' + JSON.stringify(items)));
```

On console I am getting items on multiple line i.e. subscribe is running 4 times. I want to run subscribe only once with one complete object containing data with only name and title fields.

Expected output on console is:

```
Final OBJ: [{name: 'abc', title: zzz},{name: 'abc1', title: zzz1},{name: 'abc2', title: zzz2},{name: 'abc3', title: zzz3}]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: expected output added

Comment: Map will return an array, so basically your array of objects with 3 props becomes an array with objects with 2 props. You're looking for reduce instead of map if you want a single object as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have:

```
Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .reduce((arr, item, idx, source) => {
    arr.push({
      name: item.name,
      title: item.title
    });
    return arr;
  }, [])
  .subscribe(items => console.log(JSON.stringify(items)));
```

[JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/modazibovo/edit?html,js,console)

**Edit:** It seems that [combineAll](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/combineAll.ts) should do the trick.

```
Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .map(item => {
    return Rx.Observable.of({
      name: item.name,
      title: item.title
    });
  })
  .combineAll()
  .subscribe(items => console.log(JSON.stringify(items)));
```

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/kiyuqagifi/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array. Use `forEach` array method to get items from the old array

```
var newArray = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
 newArray.push({
  name:item.name,
  title:item.title
})

})

console.log(newArray)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/bqofdczt/)